# Live stream audio using Java EE 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, io, audio-streaming

Is it possible to get a users microphone input and stream it over to another user, all through a web application programmed with Java EE 7? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that HTML5 provides `Javascript` with microphone functionality. You could use `websockets` for the data transfer between clients.